# writing variables in a file php

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate a dynamic php page from a php script and im writing codes into a file.

```
$str = "<?php $id = '548155668' ?>";
file_put_contents($file, $str);
```

it prints on file:

```
<?php  = '548155668' ?>;
```

any solution?

Comment: `$str = '..` or `$str = "<?php \$id..`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape a dollar sign,

```
$str = "<?php \$id = '548155668' ?>";
```

Or put the string into single-quotes:

```
$str = '<?php $id = \'548155668\' ?>';
```